# Using `jsonb_build_object` to return object with dynamic keys and aggregate values

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Starting with the data table below, how can I get a return JSON object with the keys for each `region` with the sum of their occurrence as the value, nested within the `region`'s `country_code`?

**Example Table**

```
+---------------------+------------------+
|    country_code     |      region      |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'CA'         |     'Ontario'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'CA'         |     'Ontario'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'CA'         |     'Ontario'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'CA'         |     'Quebec'     |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'CA'         |     'Quebec'     |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Bavaria'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Bavaria'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Bavaria'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Bavaria'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |    'Saarland'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Berlin'     |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Berlin'     |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'JP'         |     'Tokyo'      |
+---------------------+------------------+
```

**Expected Result**

```
[
  { 'CA': [
      { 'Ontario': 3 },
      { 'Quebec': 2 }
    ]
  },
  { 'DE': [
      { 'Bavaria': 4 },
      { 'Saarland': 1 },
      { 'Berlin': 2 }
    ]
  },
  { 'JP': [
      { 'Tokyo': 1 }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty

```
with tbl(country_code,region) 
  as (values ('CA', 'Ontario')
  ,('CA', 'Ontario')
  ,('CA', 'Ontario')
  ,('CA', 'Quebec')
  ,('CA', 'Quebec')
  ,('DE', 'Bavaria')
  ,('DE', 'Bavaria')
  ,('DE', 'Bavaria')
  ,('DE', 'Saarland')
  ,('DE', 'Berlin')
  ,('DE', 'Berlin')
  ,('JP', 'Tokyo')
)
, groups as (select country_code,jsonb_build_object(region,count(*)) as x from tbl group by country_code,region)
, l1 as (select jsonb_build_object(country_code,jsonb_agg(x)) as y from groups group by country_code)
select jsonb_agg(y) from l1;
```

Returns:

```
jsonb_agg                                                                                                                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
[{"CA": [{"Quebec": 2}, {"Ontario": 3}]}, {"JP": [{"Tokyo": 1}]}, {"DE": [{"Saarland": 1}, {"Berlin": 2}, {"Bavaria": 3}]}] |
```